# url is not working in live but working fine at local for cakephp project

Tags: cakephp, routes

I am using cake php version 2.4. My project is running well in my local machine and it is a simple test project. I uploaded it in live. It does not work in live and even all css file are not loading.  Should I change any server configuration?

Comment: check your servers `mod_rewrite` enable or disable, if disable need to enable

Comment: I would add some authentication or something. Not ideal to have delete action open to the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should check below situation in your Online Server :**

- DocumentRoot is properly set

  **Example :** DocumentRoot `/cake_install/app/webroot`
- `.htaccess` file is configured properly.
- `webroot` Directory have the correct permissions
- Check all other `file/folder permissions`
- Ensure apache `rewrite` module is on

> **Note :** `rewrite` module should be enabled from your online server for `CakePHP URLs`

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code in .htaccess file where app folder is located:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now it works for me.